# Object.assign is not a function

Tags: javascript, gulp, ecmascript-6, babeljs

I'm using babel with gulp and create a simple DOM library in ES6. But after running and when i'm going to use it, I got the `Object.assign is not a function` in chrome console.

this is the gulp code

```
gulp.task('scripts', function() {
    return gulp.src(src + 'js/*.js')
      .pipe(babel())
      .pipe(concat('main.js'))
      .pipe(gulp.dest(dest + 'js'));
});
```

this is the class file

```
class DOM {
    constructor( selector ) {
        var elements = document.querySelectorAll(selector);

        this.length = elements.length;

        Object.assign(this, elements);
    }

    ...

}

const dom = selector => new DOM(selector);
```

and I'm using it in client side like `dom('#elId');`

Comment: Where is that error coming from? All the code you show is from the gulp (node?) script, but your error if from Chrome. Show the relevant code

Comment: Please, do not use `concat` on Babel output. JS files are modules, they are not meant to be concatenated together. Use a bundler like browserify w/ babelify so you get the proper module behavior.

Comment: error is coming from the browser.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

As I suspect you already know, Google Chrome uses [V8](https://code.google.com/p/v8/), which supports ECMAScript 5th edition. [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) is introduced in ECMAScript 6th edition.

In order to use these additions, you need to [include the ES6 polyfill](http://babeljs.io/docs/usage/polyfill/) provided by Babel:

> This will emulate a full ES6 environment. [...]
>
> Available from the `browser-polyfill.js` file within a `babel-core` npm release. This needs to be included before all your compiled Babel code. You can either prepend it to your compiled code or include it in a `<script>` before it.

Answer (score 13):

1. Install `babel-core`:

`$ npm install babel-core --save-dev`

2. Import `polyfill` module into your js:

`import 'babel-core/polyfill';`

3. Use babel to compile your code!

Comment: Just in case anyone else hits the same issue as I did - make sure you include this before any other libraries. Seems obvious in hindsight but took a while to work out where I'd messed up :(

Comment: it's not there anymore