# Testing angular service that is also a promise

Tags: angularjs, node.js, jasmine, browserify

I'm working with `browserify` to bundle up an angular service. I'm using `jasmine` to write tests for this service, which is defined like:

```
angular
  .module('Client', [])
  .factory('client', ['url', 'otherService', '$http', '$log', client])

function client (url, otherService, $http, $log) {
  $log.debug('Creating for url %s', url)
  var apiRootPromise = $http.get(url).then(function (apiRoot) {
    $log.debug('Got api root %j', apiRoot)
    return otherService.stuff(apiRoot.data)
  })
  return Object.assign(apiRootPromise, otherService)
}
```

The following test suite:

```
describe('test client', function () {
    beforeEach(function () {
      angular.mock.module('Client')
      angular.mock.module(function ($provide) {
        $provide.value('url', 'http://localhost:8080/')
      })
    })

    it('should connect at startup', angular.mock.inject(function (client, $rootScope, $httpBackend) {
      $rootScope.$apply()
      $httpBackend.flush()
      expect(client).toBeDefined()
    }))
  })
```

Throws a `TypeError: undefined is not a constructor` on `(evaluating Object.assign(apiRootPromise, otherService)')`. I'm not sure what's happening here, but my best guess is Angular is not injecting properly the dependent service or not returning the `$http` promise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Possible duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31764414/object-assign-is-not-a-function)

`Object.assign` is introduced in ECMAScript 6th edition and is not currently natively supported in all browsers. Try using a polyfill for `Object.assign`. Here's one:

```
    if (typeof Object.assign != 'function') {
  (function () {
    Object.assign = function (target) {
      'use strict';
      if (target === undefined || target === null) {
        throw new TypeError('Cannot convert undefined or null to object');
      }

      var output = Object(target);
      for (var index = 1; index < arguments.length; index++) {
        var source = arguments[index];
        if (source !== undefined && source !== null) {
          for (var nextKey in source) {
            if (source.hasOwnProperty(nextKey)) {
              output[nextKey] = source[nextKey];
            }
          }
        }
      }
      return output;
    };
  })();
}
```

Otherwise, your code is [working in this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7xskpu6b/1/) (I had to fill in a few blanks, but the general gist is there)