# WebView not loading certain pages

Tags: android, webview, android-webview

Unable to load following webpage in WebView

https://6awlanow.com/about/faqs

Tried following so far -

```
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
    webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
    webView.getSettings().setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
    webView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
    webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
    webView.getSettings().setUserAgentString("Android WebView");
    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

      @Override
      public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request) {
        view.loadUrl(request.getUrl().getPath());
        //if (progressDialog != null && progressDialog.isShowing()) {
        //  progressDialog.dismiss();
        //}
        return true;
      }

      //If you will not use this method url links are opeen in new brower not in webview
      @Override
      public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        view.loadUrl(url);
        return true;
      }

      //Show loader on url load
      @Override
      public void onLoadResource(WebView view, String url) {
      }
      @Override
      public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        try {
          //if (progressDialog.isShowing()) {
          //  progressDialog.dismiss();
          //}
        } catch (Exception exception) {
          exception.printStackTrace();
        }
      }

      @Override
      public void onReceivedError(
        WebView view, WebResourceRequest request, WebResourceError error
      ) {
        //progressDialog.dismiss();
        super.onReceivedError(view, request, error);
      }

    });
```

I have already provided **internet** permission. The URL loads fine everywhere, except on WebView. I get following error -

Get following Info on my console -

```
I: [INFO:CONSOLE(31)] "Uncaught TypeError: Object.assign is not a function", source: https://6awlanow.com/app.c98a13d5a9fdd32775ca.js (31)
I: [INFO:CONSOLE(0)] "Error: Invalid negative value for <rect> attribute ry="-.125"", source: https://6awlanow.com/about/faqs (0)
I: [INFO:CONSOLE(0)] "Error: Invalid negative value for <rect> attribute ry="-.125"", source: https://6awlanow.com/about/faqs (0)
I: [INFO:CONSOLE(0)] "Error: Invalid negative value for <rect> attribute ry="-.125"", source: https://6awlanow.com/about/faqs (0)
I: [INFO:CONSOLE(0)] "Error: Invalid negative value for <rect> attribute ry="-.125"", source: https://6awlanow.com/about/faqs (0)
I: [INFO:CONSOLE(0)] "Error: Invalid negative value for <rect> attribute ry="-.125"", source: https://6awlanow.com/about/faqs (0)
I: [INFO:CONSOLE(0)] "Error: Invalid negative value for <rect> attribute ry="-.125"", source: https://6awlanow.com/about/faqs (0)
I: [INFO:CONSOLE(0)] "Error: Invalid negative value for <rect> attribute ry="-.125"", source: https://6awlanow.com/about/faqs (0)
I: [INFO:CONSOLE(0)] "Error: Invalid negative value for <rect> attribute ry="-.125"", source: https://6awlanow.com/about/faqs (0)
I: [INFO:CONSOLE(0)] "Error: Invalid negative value for <rect> attribute ry="-.125"", source: https://6awlanow.com/about/faqs (0)
I: [INFO:CONSOLE(0)] "Error: Invalid negative value for <rect> attribute ry="-.125"", source: https://6awlanow.com/about/faqs (0)
I: [INFO:CONSOLE(0)] "Error: Invalid negative value for <rect> attribute ry="-.125"", source: https://6awlanow.com/about/faqs (0)
I: [INFO:CONSOLE(0)] "Error: Invalid negative value for <rect> attribute ry="-.125"", source: https://6awlanow.com/about/faqs (0)
```

Comment: Testing on older version device?

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya No, testing on Lollipop device.

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya Still same issue

Comment: I think you have to refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31764414/1083957) question.

Comment: @azizbekian You mean to say that backend has to do this? But the url is loading on mobile browsers properly, just not loading on WebView.

Comment: @RohanKandwal if your internet permission is `INTERNET` https://stackoverflow.com/a/31533625/1032167 and you see the log message you provided can you show what you see on the screen? some error message?

Comment: @varren Permission is correct since I am able to load another websites when I change URL. I am not able to load only this particular URL. There are no errors except what I pasted in question. All I see is a blank white screen.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use below code and it should work, I tested and it worked.

```
public class WebViewEx extends AppCompatActivity {

    private WebView webView;
    private ProgressDialog progDailog;
    Activity activity;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_web_view_ex);

        webView = findViewById(R.id.webView);
        activity = this;

        progDailog = ProgressDialog.show(activity, "Loading", "Please wait...", true);
        progDailog.setCancelable(false);


        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
        webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
        webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                progDailog.show();
                view.loadUrl(url);

                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, final String url) {
                progDailog.dismiss();
            }
        });

        webView.loadUrl("https://6awlanow.com/about/faqs");
    }
}
```

Your XML will be like below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Below is the result I got in WebView:

[image]

I hope this will resolve your issue and let me know if you have any query.

Comment: That's strange, the url loaded for you is correct, however it is still not loading for me. Other URLs loading fine for me except this one still. I will create a project on GitHub with the relevant code in few hours. Please have a look at it then.

Comment: @RohanKandwal sure and then share the link with me, I will have a look and find out what's the issue.

Comment: @RohanKandwal your code is working fine on my device. The webview is opening the URL. Did you try to run your application on any other device?

Comment: @PankajMudra That's strange... It is working fine on some emulators but not on others, but since it is working fine on mobiles, it works for now.

Answer (score 1):

what worked for me is

1 .Enabling dom Storage and javascript

```
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webView.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true);
webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
```

2.running webview on handler

```
 new Handler().post(new Runnable() {
                   @Override
                   public void run() {

                       webView.loadUrl(webview_url);

                   }
               });
```

Comment: @stdunbar  May be not better but only this worked for me. Running on new handler. So i thought it might help someone.